# Excel Macro to fill gaps in date from further down the column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I would like to fill in some blank cells. This part of the spreadsheet looks like:

```
Person        Workplace
Name A
Name B
Name C         Place A
Name D
Name E         Place B
Name F
Name G
Name H         Place C
```

'Name A' and 'Name B' need to also have the Workplace 'Place A', 'Name D' needs the workplace 'Place B' and 'Name F' and 'Name G' need 'Place C'.

I have written some code (workplace data starts in column D5):

```
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D5", "D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = Range("D5").End(xlDown)
        End If
    Next cell
```

However, this simply fills all the cells with 'Place A'.

I thought as I filled in cells the '.End(xlDown)' cell would dynamically change to the new last cell with the new place. Can someone help me fix this to make it work?

I would avoid macros altogether except there are a number of other operations to perform on a very large dataset and I will need to do this many times over the next weeks and months ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like so, or mess about with `end(xlUp)` also `.fillup/down`

```
Sub fillin()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim s As String

Set r = Range("a1:b8")
Set c = r.Cells(1, 2)

Do Until c.Row > r.Rows.Count

    s = c.End(xlDown).Value

    c.Resize(c.End(xlDown).Row - c.Row, 1).Value = s

    Set c = r.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I've made this work with my dataset and done some of the work to extend it to the general case. I note just one thing ... as this is a resize, if you run the macro twice on the same data you get an oddity. For my use case, this works well - thank you for helping!

Comment: @Carina no problem, you dont really need all the range, just the column of values i suppose.  Happy to help